# Outlined steps for creating a database? (NoSQL)

Tags: java, database-design, nosql, database

I have a school project in which I am creating a Non Relational Document (or Key Value if suggested to) DBMS. Pretty much I am only looking for the outline of what I will need to implement. While I have an idea in mind, I would like to know approaches other people would take to do the same project.

The DBMS is going to be used with a basic web application that stores user login info (password, name, email, zipcode) and a short message (similar to twitter). The web application will retrieve data based on different factors and write to the DB. I wanted to make it possible to be used on 2 different machines (similar to a horizontal scale), but that might be thrown out due to time.

I plan to program in Java, but I am open to using another language if necessary.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A key/value is easy; it can also be used as the basis for building a non-key-value store. The important thing is to work out a workable API. You could store nodes that have a name, and access two kinds of properties (child nodes and attributes), for example.

The question's rather broad; what design criteria do you have?

Comment: All I need to do is implement the main features of a NoSQL database. I am looking for an outline. Thanks for mentioning an API, forgot all about that. I may be ignorant to what you need as for design criteria.

Comment: Well, the main thing *I* would probably do is start writing some tests (i.e., client code) that could show me how I want to use the nosql engine; it doesn't matter that there's no engine until you have an idea of what the API is. Then write that API. Classic TDD.